# PendingIntent.GetBroadcast in C# is not letting me create notifications

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications

I'm currently trying to create notifications in Visual Studio using Xamarin, and I'm having trouble with the Android app.

This is the notification service class that connects to the notification reciever, then should send a notification after a certain number of seconds. Problem is, the line with pendingIntent.GetBroadcast always stops the code in its tracks. No error message appears, so I'm not sure why this particular line is incorrect.

Could anyone give advice or point out what's wrong? Or would it be better to scrap this and trya new approach.

I'm more than happy to provide any further information to help determine what is wrong. The WriteLine commands are just to see how far along the code gets, and it goes about as far as saying "Testing 2"

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using WCDP_FMRS.Services;
using Context = Android.Content.Context;

namespace WCDP_FMRS.Droid.Services
{
    // Implement the INotificationService for Android
    public class AndroidNotificationService : INotificationService
    {
        public void ScheduleNotification(string title, string message, int seconds)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Testing 1");

            var alarmIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(AndroidNotificationReceiver));
            var notifyTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds);
            alarmIntent.PutExtra("title", title);
            alarmIntent.PutExtra("message", message);

            Console.WriteLine("Testing 2");

            **var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);**
            var alarmManager = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;

            Console.WriteLine("Testing 2.5");

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M)
            {
                alarmManager.SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, notifyTime.ToLocalTime().Ticks / 10000, pendingIntent);
                Console.WriteLine("Testing 3");
            }
            else if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                alarmManager.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, notifyTime.ToLocalTime().Ticks / 10000, pendingIntent);
                Console.WriteLine("Testing 4");
            }
            else
            {
                alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, notifyTime.ToLocalTime().Ticks / 10000, pendingIntent);
                Console.WriteLine("Testing 5");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Testing 6");

        }

        public void RequestAuthorization()
        {

            NotificationChannelHelper.CreateNotificationChannel(Application.Context);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation of [PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_MUTABLE),we know that :

> Up until `Build.VERSION_CODES.R`, `PendingIntents` are assumed to be
> mutable by default, unless `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` is set. Starting with
> `Build.VERSION_CODES.S`, it will be required to explicitly specify the
> mutability of PendingIntents on creation with either (@link
> #FLAG_IMMUTABLE} or `FLAG_MUTABLE`. It is strongly recommended to use
> `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` when creating a `PendingIntent`. `FLAG_MUTABLE` should
> only be used when some functionality relies on modifying the
> underlying intent, e.g. any `PendingIntent` that needs to be used with
> inline reply or bubbles.

So, you can try to replace code :

```
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
```

with:

```
 var pendingIntentFlags = (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S) 
                ? PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Mutable
                : PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent;


 var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, resultIntent, pendingIntentFlags);
```